# CodeIgniter - Convert GIF to JPG? Possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick

I am looking to accomplish this in CodeIgniter specifically.

The PHP App I am coding allows a user to upload either a jpg or an animated gif image. On the next step I want to allow the user to use jCrop to crop a few different size thumbnails. This would require me to convert a new copy of the animated gif to a jpg. My code works fine with uploaded jpg images, but creates a broken image for gif files. Is what I am trying to do possible?

My Code:

```
                // Create image to crop
            $config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
            $config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_dir_path') . $file_path . 'original.' . $file_ext;
            chmod($config['source_image'], 0777);
            $config['new_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_dir_path') . $file_path . 'crop-me.jpg';
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
            $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: A very quick Google search found this: http://www.robertmullaney.com/2010/09/18/codeigniter-image_lib-convert-jpg-gif-png/. -1 ("Does not show any research effort")

Comment: This is my second day "researching" this, did you actually try the extended library you link to or just have blind faith? It is a bit out of date and filled with bugs which I found out yesterday, I will try and code through them then if this is the only option around. Thanks for the down votes! lol...

Comment: How can it be outdated? It's from 18/09/2010, that wasn't THAT long ago, and the GIF/JPEG specs haven't changed THAT much in that period. Also, most libraries on the net contains bugs, it's part of our jobs as programmers to fix them when we use them.

Comment: The code is / was not valid for this version of CodeIgniter, not sure why that was difficult to understand. The constructor, some of the global variables called, etc...I continued to fix bugs with new ones being generated. I understand your point that it's part of jobs to fix bugs, but you linked to a non-functional CI library and then convinced a group of people to down vote me even though you provided only sarcasm and quick judgement.

Comment: Yes, I am unexperienced with GIF files, hence the reason I came here for help and only found you. I finally found an extremely simple solution and will provide that as the answer for my question for others.

Comment: The point was not the link itself, the point was the very quick find. There are a multitude of solutions out there, and even if one is not tailor made to CodeIgniter, it's trivial to change a class into a codeigniter library. Nonetheless, I understand your point, I am removing my vote, and hope others will do the same.

Comment: Would love to know what "bugs" there were/are. Even though it was originally written for 1.7.2 (eg: php4 was still supported), the only people reporting "bugs" were "i think it should do this" issues, not how it was intended to work. Read all the comments and if you don't know... ask ;)

Comment: It's been well over a year, I am not working on this project anymore and have no intention of going through that lib code again. It was filled with bugs with the latest version of CI at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those interested in my solution, I simply used the built in GD PHP functions. I have little experience dealing with gif files so I was expecting this to be difficult. The fact of the matter is the CodeIgniter Image_lib and extended library (Which I never got to work properly) is overkill for this.

Here is what I used:

```
$image = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_gif_image);
imagejpeg($image, $output_path_with_jpg_extension);
```

Very easy and worked perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: OC indicated "in CodeIgniter specifically"

Comment: Yes I said specifically, not exclusively. I was open to alternatives. If CI is able to handle this issue better than two lines of code using built in PHP functions, then show me.

Comment: The good news, Robert M. ... You can do PHP in CodeIgniter... :P  Frameworks are great, but sometimes you need to go around them.